# Calculating weekly averages in Power BI matrix using DAX and Power Query

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I want to add a Average column by week in my Matrix in power BI. I need help to compute the the formula.

Below are the details -

Corp_Wk_Num is a column with weeks 1 to 52 per year.
Weekday 3 - I have created a column in power BI to get the 7 days of the week using -
`WEEKDAY 3 =` `SWITCH(Query1[CAL_DAY_OF_WK_NUM],1,"Sunday",2,"Monday",3,"Tuesday",4,"Wednesday",5,"Thursday",6,"Friday",7,"Saturday")`

values- Assembly Actual case per hr = is a computed measure -
`Assembly Actual Cases Per/Hr = IF([SUMOF ASSEMBLY_ACTUALTIME/60]=0,BLANK(), [SUMOF ASSEMBLY_QTY]/[SUMOF ASSEMBLY_ACTUALTIME/60])`

PS. [SUMOF ASSEMBLY_QTY] and [SUMOF ASSEMBLY_ACTUALTIME/60] are measures which is calculated as follows -
`SUMOF ASSEMBLY_ACTUALTIME/60 = [SUMOF ASSEMBLY_ACTUALTIME]/60 SUMOF ASSEMBLY_QTY = SUM(Query1[ASSEMBLY_Qty])`

I am trying to get the weekly average into the matrix.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6wl1.png  - what I have

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUcLn.png - what I need

Comment: You can take an example to manually calculate according to your formula and check whether it is what you want: 1pc in 2hrs and 2pcs in 3hrs - what is  the result according to your formula and is that what you want?

Comment: Unrelated to my first comment, you may also have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-divide-function-operator

Comment: Unrelated, but you can simplify your weekday 3 column if you have a base date column using the `FORMAT([date],"dddd")` function.

Comment: What behavior are you currently getting when you insert your `[Assembly Actual Cases Per/Hr]` measure into a table visual with the `Corp_Wk_Num` column?

Comment: I have added 2 snaps of what I am looking for and what I have. If that helps.

Comment: Have you tried enabling column sub-totals in the formatting pane of the visual?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling column sub-totals in the formatting pane of the visual? Looking at your measure, it looks like enabling this should do what you want it to do.

[image: Enable Column Sub-Totals In Formatting Pane]

One further note, it is best practice to replace the division operator with the DIVIDE() function. This will automatically handle #DIV/0 errors.

```
Assembly Actual Cases Per/Hr = DIVIDE([SUMOF ASSEMBLY_QTY],[SUMOF ASSEMBLY_ACTUALTIME/60])
```